# Numpy eigensystem solver returns improper matrix

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

I've been trying to use the output of `numpy.linalg.eigh` as a
rotation matrix, but the matrix formed from the eigenvectors it
returns is improper; that is, it's not a pure rotation, but a
combination of a rotation and a reflection. You can see that as
follows.

```
GG = np.array([[2.0, 0.146, 0.0064],
               [0.146, -1.0, 0.0003],
               [0.0064, 0.0003, -1.0]])
vals,vecs = np.linalg.eigh(GG)
np.linalg.det(vecs)
```

This returns -0.99999999999. A pure rotation would return 1.0.

Am I missing something about the way this solver works? How can I
get `eigh` or some other function to return a proper rotation
matrix? Perhaps the fact that this matrix is traceless causes
problems?

Comment: Multilply a  column of `vects` by `np.linalg.det(vecs)`?

Comment: You have no reason to presume that the result is a rotation matrix - just that the eigenvectors will be (for your matrix) orthonormal. You can't guarantee the order that they come out in, and swapping two columns of a matrix reverses the sign of the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a square matrix `A`, and let us assume `v` is an eigenvector with `e` the corresponding eigenvalue, that is

```
A*v = e*v
```

Now consider what happens if we scale `v` by some scalar `s`, lets set `w = v*s`:

```
A*w = A*(v*s) = (A*v)*s = (e*v) = e*(v*s) = e*w
```

It turns out `w` is also an eigenvector for eigenvalue `e`! Actually eigenvectors are only defined up to scalar multiples, so the convention is that we normalize them to a length `1`. So if you scale one eigenvector by `-1` you still have a valid eigensystem, this time with determinant `+0.999...9`.

Finally, why is it `0.999...9` instead of 1? We are using [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), which is not exact. If you are trying to solve numerical problems I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with floating point numbers, their problems and limitations and the best practices.

Evidently

Comment: The limited precision doesn't worry me. Does the fact that the determinant is -1 mean that the coordinate axes formed by the eigenvectors form a left-handed coordinate system? And multiplying one eigenvector by -1 results in a right-handed coordinate system?

Comment: Right for this 3x3 system you can say that with a positive determinant, the handedness is preserved. Basically the determinant tells you the volume of a shape of volume 1 , after it has been transformed by the matrix.